# showing extra text in hide/show button

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is that when I press the button paragraph's text should be hide and will show "Click to see more" and again pressing the same button the paragraph's text should be visible.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I answer your question.
but here is a simple solution using vanilla JS by setting the height to your paragaph and set its css `overflow` attribute to `hidden`. Then programmatically set  the `overflow` attribute to `none` you can archive as the following:

```
<body>
<p style="width: 500px; height: 20px; overflow: hidden;" id="myParagraph">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis amet sunt laudantium officia 
    sed porro dolorem odit iusto quidem enim ab nihil, quos quod ad quam atque veritatis iure architecto?

</p>
<button id="btnSeeMore">See More</button>
<script>    
    var seeMore = true;
    var myParagraph = document.getElementById('myParagraph');
    var myBtn = document.getElementById('btnSeeMore');
    
    myBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        console.log("event",e);
        if(seeMore){
            
            console.log("if");
            myParagraph.style.overflow = "none"; 
            myParagraph.style.height = "100px"; 
            myBtn.innerHTML = "See Less";
            seeMore = false;
           
        }else{
            console.log("else");
            myParagraph.style.overflow = "hidden"; 
            myParagraph.style.height = "20px"; 
            myBtn.innerHTML = "See More";
            seeMore = true;
        }
        
    });
</script>
```

Here is jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/jtdb6ecf/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the code that you need

```
    <div id="myParagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse nostrum 
    dolore sapiente ducimus facere accusamus illo libero, vero nihil impedit.</div>
<div>
    <button id="btnShowMore">Show More</button>
    <button id="btnHide">Hide</button>
</div>
<script>
    const myParagraph = document.getElementById("myParagraph");
    const btnShowMore = document.getElementById("btnShowMore");
    const btnHide = document.getElementById("btnHide");

    let myText = myParagraph.innerHTML;
    btnShowMore.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        // everytime when the user click show more
        myParagraph.innerHTML += myText;
    })
    btnHide.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        // if you want to display the first text use myText if you don't want to siplay anything use ""
        myParagraph.innerHTML = myText;
    })
</script>
```

you can do it by CSS by using display none or inline but here you don't need it, but here is code:

```
    <script>
    const myParagraph = document.getElementById("myParagraph");
    const btnShowMore = document.getElementById("btnShowMore");
    const btnHide = document.getElementById("btnHide");

    let myText = myParagraph.innerHTML;
    btnShowMore.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        // everytime when the user click show more
        myParagraph.innerHTML += myText;
        myParagraph.style.display = "inline";
    })
    btnHide.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        // if you want to display the first text use myText if you don't want to siplay anything use ""
        myParagraph.style.display = "none":
    })
</script>
```